# How to filters data at node level in Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let suppose we have two match and now we want something like that 
(match1-match2)

```
match (u:User)-[r:HAS_RESOURCES]-(resource:Resource) where id(u)=1484
 match (resource1:Resource)-[r1:OWNED_BY_USER]-(owner:User) where resource1.isPublished=true return resource1
```

This cypher we made . So now we want something like this id(resource1)-id(resource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can filter resources that are not in a collection.

Make sure to have an index on :Resource(isPublished) otherwise you have to scan across all resources.

```
match (u:User)-[r:HAS_RESOURCES]-(resource:Resource) where id(u)=1484
with collect(resource) as resources
match (resource1:Resource) 
where resource1.isPublished=true and NOT (resource1 IN resources)
return resource1
```

Comment: Please provide more details on Indexing in Neo4j