# Full Text indexing in Neo4j with Spring Data Neo4j 3.2.0

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

We need fulltext indexing in Neo4j Database with Spring Data Neo4j . Actually I am studying from that link http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/indexing-create-advanced.html

but now methods of it are deprecated  . 
I study more about it from here http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-neo4j/3.2.0.M1/reference/pdf/spring-data-neo4j-reference.pdf
.I am confuse what to do . Michael Hunger yesterday told us about indexing on that Question [How to filters data at node level in Neo4j Cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477459/how-to-filters-data-at-node-level-in-neo4j-cypher) .
 We do indexing at Domain Level

```
@Indexed(indexName = "people-search", indexType=IndexType.FULLTEXT) String username
```

Please give more details on it

Comment: Full text indexing is still to be done via manual indexes, full support with schema indexes will come in a later version of Neo4j. So you're doing it right

Answer (score 1):

We get a solution

```
@Indexed(indexName = "peopleSearch", indexType=IndexType.FULLTEXT)
     String postText

 @Indexed(indexName = "peopleSearch", indexType=IndexType.FULLTEXT) String username
```

And then in Cypher we use

```
START item=node:peopleSearch("postText:v* OR username:*a")
 return id(item) ,labels(item)
```

If you have any better approach then Provide us . Thanks